# A ground fault on a wye-connected ungrounded system

Tags: power-supply

In a wye connection, if ungrounded at the neutral, in case of a line to ground fault, the unfaulted phase-to-ground voltages are increased in by √3 of the original value.

My question is what about the line voltages of the unfaulted phases?

Say a line to ground fault occur on phase A.

Vbn and Vcn will increase by 1.732.

What about Vbc?

And Vca and Vab?

Comment: Draw the phasors. What changes? What doesn't?

Comment: Surely though if the initial state is that no part of the circuit is grounded then no part, measured in isolation, has a voltage relative to ground.

Comment: "Vbn and Vcn will increase by 1.732." Are you sure about that? Why? are you using "n" to denote neutral, or grountd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at this phasor diagram of before and after and, you should see your answer: -

[image]